# Validação de CPF no Android - Erro no ArrayList

Tags: android

Tenho esta classe para validar campo de CPF no android, porem está dando erro na linha:  `ArrayList<Separador> posicaoSeparadoresTexto(String mascara)`

Segue abaixo código completo:

```
package com.mcavalini.lib;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Utils {

    public static int tamanhoMaximo(String mascara) {
        String novaString = removeCaracteresEspeciais(mascara);
        return novaString.length();
    }

    public static String removeCaracteresEspeciais(String str) {

        String[] caracteresEspeciais = {"\\.", ",", "-", ":", "\\(", "\\)", "ª", "\\|", "\\\\", "°", "\\/"};

        for (int i = 0; i < caracteresEspeciais.length; i++) {
            str = str.replaceAll(caracteresEspeciais[i], "");
        }

        return str;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Separador> posicaoSeparadoresTexto(String mascara) {
        ArrayList<Separador> listaSeparadores = new ArrayList<Separador>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mascara.length(); i++) {
            if ( (mascara.substring(i, i+1).equals(new String(","))) ||
                 (mascara.substring(i, i+1).equals(new String("."))) ||
                 (mascara.substring(i, i+1).equals(new String("-"))) ||
                 (mascara.substring(i, i+1).equals(new String("/"))) ||
                 (mascara.substring(i, i+1).equals(new String("("))) ||
                 (mascara.substring(i, i+1).equals(new String(")")))) {
                listaSeparadores.add(new Separador(new Integer(i), mascara.substring(i, i+1)));
            }
        }

        return listaSeparadores;
    }

    public static String padString(String numero, int tamanhoMaximo, int tamanhoMascara, ArrayList<Separador> listaSeparadores) {
        String stringMascarada = "";
        boolean isPad = true;
        int indicePadString = 0;
        int indiceNumero = 0;
        int tamanhoNumero = numero.length();

        while (isPad) {
            for (Separador separador : listaSeparadores) {
                if (separador.getPosicao().intValue() == indicePadString) {
                    stringMascarada += separador.getCaracter();
                    indicePadString += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ((indiceNumero < tamanhoMaximo) && (indiceNumero < tamanhoNumero) ) {
                stringMascarada += numero.substring(indiceNumero, indiceNumero+1);
            } 

            indicePadString += 1;
            indiceNumero += 1;

            if (indiceNumero >= tamanhoNumero)
                isPad = false;
        }

        return stringMascarada;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.mcavalini.lib;

import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.NumberKeyListener;

public class KeyListenerNumber extends NumberKeyListener {

    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
        return new char[] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.mcavalini.core;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.mcavalini.lib.KeyListenerNumber;
import com.mcavalini.lib.Utils;

public class MaskEditText extends EditText {
    private String mascara;
    private int tamanhoMascara;
    private int tamanhoMaximo;

    private boolean isUpdating;

    private KeyListenerNumber keyListenerNumber;

    public static String CPF_MASK = "   .   .   -  ";
    public static String CEP_MASK = "     -   ";
    public static String TELEFONE_8DIGITOS_MASK = "(  )    -    ";

    public MaskEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }   

    public int getTamanhoMascara() {
        return tamanhoMascara;
    }

    public void init(String mascara) {
        this.mascara = mascara;
        this.tamanhoMascara = mascara.length();
        this.tamanhoMaximo = Utils.tamanhoMaximo(mascara);

        keyListenerNumber = new KeyListenerNumber();
        this.setKeyListener(keyListenerNumber);
        this.setText("");

        this.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String stringAtual = s.toString();

                if (isUpdating) {
                    isUpdating = false;
                    return;
                }

                String numero = stringAtual.replaceAll("[^0-9]*", "");

                if (numero.length() > tamanhoMaximo)
                    numero = numero.substring(0, tamanhoMaximo);

                String campo = Utils.padString(numero, tamanhoMaximo, tamanhoMascara, Utils.posicaoSeparadoresTexto(MaskEditText.this.mascara));

                isUpdating = true;

                MaskEditText.this.setText(campo);
                MaskEditText.this.setSelection(campo.length());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
    <com.mcavalini.core.MaskEditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCpf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <requestFocus />   
    </com.mcavalini.core.MaskEditText>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: Cannot resolver symbol Separator

Comment: E de onde vem essa classe `Separador`?

Comment: Eu peguei este exemplo pronto de: http://www.guj.com.br/java/281645-mascara-no-edittext-do-android

Comment: O problema é que a classe `Separador` não é definida em lado algum. Se for à página do site de onde você retirou o código, há uma entrada de alguém que faz uma pergunta sobre o assunto e não obteve resposta. Sem essa classe o código não compila.

Comment: OK, obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar essa pergunta porque o problema (falta da classe `Separador`) já foi identificado pelo AP, é pontual e dificilmente ajudaria outras pessoas da comunidade.

Comment: @LuizVieira Não feche. Essa classe é fácil de prover. Estou escrevendo uma resposta agora.

Comment: @Victor Legal você ter provido a classe. Mas ainda assim essa pergunta me parece pouco aproveitável, você não acha? Você teve que interpretar todo o código do AP pra *inferir* como seria a classe `Separador`, sendo que a necessidade dele (validar CPF) poderia ser realizada de inúmeras outras formas talvez mais simples e sem os potenciais problemas que você mesmo cita na sua resposta. Enfim, eu realmente me pergunto se essa pergunta tem potencial pra ajudar alguém mais além do AP...

Comment: @LuizVieira Se o AP encontrou este código no GUJ, resolveu tentar e teve um problema, então acredito que o mesmo poderia acontecer com mais pessoas. E pessoas que procurarem no google sobre validação de CPF em android vão encontrar esta pergunta e do GUJ também. Além disso, se alguém puder dar uma resposta melhor que a minha, não vejo porque impedir. Entretanto concordo que a pergunta não é das melhores, mas ainda acho salvável. E também concordo que existem maneiras bem melhores de se validar um CPF em android, e olha só, alguém poderia postar isso como uma resposta!

Comment: @Victor Entendo seus pontos. Enfim, se for pra errar prefiro fazê-lo em prol do conteúdo e do AP. Então retirei meu voto pra fechar. Vamos ver se a pergunta melhora. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem como já disseram nos comentários, está faltando a classe `Separador`. Vamos bolar esta classe:

```
public class Separador {
    private final Integer posicao;
    private final String caracter;

    public Separador(Integer posicao, String caracter) {
        this.posicao = posicao;
        this.caracter = caracter;
    }

    public Integer getPosicao() {
        return posicao;
    }

    public String getCaracter() {
        return caracter;
    }
}
```

E com isso, o seu código deve compilar e funcionar.

---

Entretanto, o código ainda tem vários outros problemas:

- Ele não usa autoboxing e autounboxing de forma adequada, usando `new Integer(i)` ao invés de apenas `i` e depois usando o `getPosicao().intValue()` ao invés de simplesmente `getPosicao()`.
- A classe `Separador` que coloquei acima foi feita para ser compatível com o código, mas poderia ser melhor se `posicao` fosse `int` e não `Integer` e `caracter` fosse `char` e não `String`, mas para isso teria que alterar a classe `Utils`.
- Utilizar `new String(",")` é desnecessário, basta `","`.
- Usar como tipo `ArrayList<Separador>` ao invés de `List<Separador>` não é uma boa prática, vai contra o princípio *code to an interface*.
- A presença de uma classe chamada `Utils` cheio de métodos estáticos aparenta ser algum anti-padrão mais profundo.
- Deve haver outros problemas ainda.